# DELETE SQL not firing - call to a member function exec() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP script that takes two POST values and then uses them to find and delete a row from my database as so:

```
<?php
$incomingListNameD = $_POST['text'];
$incomingNewContentD = $_POST['text2'];

    //MAIN DB function for removing items

try
{
    //open the database  PDO METHOD
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:listDB.sqlite');

    $db->exec("INSERT INTO ListItems (ParentList, Content) VALUES ('Poopy', 'Ruglegs');");

    //Prepared statement version of values remove

    $qry = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ListItems (ParentList,Content) VALUES (?,?)");
    $qry->execute(array($incomingListNameD,$incomingNewContentD));

    // close the database connection
    $db = NULL;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The problem is I keep getting an error:

```
call to a member function exec() on a non-object.
```

The Poopy Ruglegs (don't ask, just added for debug) line is added so I do have a handle that is working; my DELETE just won't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: That isn't the right syntax for a DELETE statement - it's `DELETE FROM table WHERE condition`

Comment: what says `var_dump($db)` ?

Comment: You are doing error checking wrong. PDO does not throw exceptions by default.

Comment: your prepare() failed, returning a boolean false. Your code simply assumes success, and blundered onwards. NEVER assume success.

Comment: Thanks  andrewsi, so    $qry = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ListItems WHERE (ParentList,Content) VALUES (?,?)");

Comment: @KolKurtz - what exactly are you trying to do? Delete the row, or remove some items from it?

Comment: Delete the row. I just tried $qry = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ListItems WHERE ParentList = ? AND Contents = ? ");  That doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @KolKurtz - The second field there is `Content`, not `Contents`. You can get the errors from PDO using `var_dump($qry->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($db->ErrorInfo())`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$db` is correctly constructed before calling `exec()`. I'm guessing it is not instantiated properly.

For debugging:

```
var_dump($db)
```

For handling:

```
if(isset($db)) {
...
} else { 
...
}
```

Comment: Its set. It also manages to write the Poopy Ruglegs row so I think were fine there.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you think it adds it to the db but it's already in there. There has to be a reason the code fails on the exec() call.

Comment: I've checked many many times now. I'm emptying the db each time so I know exactly what is in there and then checking after each operation. I've sacked off the prepared statements for now as I can't seem to get the right syntax for a multi condition DELETE with a prepared statement and no-one seemed to want to tell me.